# Laravel save nested model

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am using Laravel 4 and got stuck with a problem.

I have 3 models: User, Project, Task.

Relationships:

- User belongsToMany('Project')
- Project belongsToMany('User')
- Project belongsToMany('Task')
- Task belongsTo('Project')

I want to store a task but with no luck. The following code maybe tells in more detail what I want to accomplish:

```
Auth::user()->projects($projectId)->tasks()->save($task);
```

With that code I get:

```
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::tasks()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save your task first.

Then you can try...

```
Auth::user()->projects()->find($projectID)->tasks()->associate($task);
```

You may also need to modify your Project/Task relationship.  The inverse of `belongsToMany` is always `belongsToMany`.  I am thinking you will probably need `hasMany` and `belongsTo` instead.

Edit:

Sorry I think I lead you in the wrong direction, I finally got this working.

```
$task = new Task;
$task->name = 'Some super ultra task';

Auth::user()->projects()->where('projects.id', $projectID)->first()->tasks()->save($task);
```

Additionally, I think I made it harder than it needed to be.

```
$project = Project::find($projectID);
$project->tasks()->save($task);
```

That should work exactly the same.  Since we know the ID of the project we are looking for, we shouldn't really need to go through the user model first.

To check that a user owns a project before saving, you can add this function to your `Project` model.

```
public function ownedByUser($user_id)
{
    if(User::find($user_id)->projects()->count()) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Then to you use it, here is what I did...

```
$project = Project::find($projectID);

if($project->ownedByUser(Auth::user()->id)) {
    $project->tasks()->save($task);
} else {
    echo 'This isn\'t your projec to edit, fool!';
}
```

Comment: Almost there.. Now I got an error: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'id' in where clause is ambiguous (SQL: select * from `projects` inner join `project_user` on `projects`.`id` = `project_user`.`project_id` where `project_user`.`user_id` = 1 and `id` = 1 limit 1)

Comment: Also tried to change the Project/Task relationship but had no effect.

Comment: The SQL error is caused by ->find($projectId) but I can't figure out how to overcome the issue.

Comment: It took a few tries but I think I figured it out.  I updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks. The last snippet you wrote does the job but how to check if the user really owns the project so user could only add tasks to his/hers project?

Comment: You could add a function to your model which will check if it's okay and then update.  I'll update my answer with it

Comment: You're a saviour :) Thank you very much.